# Is it bad practice to have two pages in a flask app use the same html?

Tags: python, html, flask

So, I have two pages in my app that currently use the same html, and I pass arguments to render_template to specify a couple of things that should differ between the two pages (mostly just headings and table data).

Would it be better to have separate html files that both extend a common file?

Answer (score 0):

A common way to build this sort of functionality in flask is to use [Jinja](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/). Specifically their concept of [child templates](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#child-template). That will allow you to refactor common HTML out of your templates.

Here is the example from the linked docs:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}Index{% endblock %}
{% block head %}
    {{ super() }}
    <style type="text/css">
        .important { color: #336699; }
    </style>
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
    <h1>Index</h1>
    <p class="important">
      Welcome to my awesome homepage.
    </p>
{% endblock %}
```